# What factors cause data not to go through in sockets in python (or python/node.js)?

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, pycharm

(Suggestions for rephrasing questions?)

I'm sending data over a socket with client/server pattern. When
I run python (in pycharms) the output on the receiving end doesn't get data. 
However, when I use the re-rerun icon  (in pycharms) the data goes through.

I'm confused to be honest by this behavior and not sure what to ask besides telling you what I observe.

Here is the client code. It's talking to server setup with `net` (node.js)

**client.py**

```
import socket   // python version 2.7.*

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 7000))
    client.sendall("test data to transmit") 

    data = client.recv(50)
    client.close()

    print 'Received', repr(data)
```

**server.js**

```
var net = require('net');  // node v0.10.21 (latest)
var PYTHON = {HOST :'127.0.0.1', PORT :7000};

net.createServer(function(socket) {
    console.log('CONNECTION for Python: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+ socket.remotePort);

    var body = '';
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA ' + socket.remoteAddress );
        body += data;
    });

    socket.on('close', function(err) {
        console.log('finish transmitting data... ');
        console.log(body);
    });
}).listen(PYTHON.PORT, PYTHON.HOST, function() {
    console.log('---->socket to talk to python '
                    + PYTHON.HOST + ':' + PYTHON.PORT);
});
```

**update**: added server.js code

Comment: What are you using for the server end? If it's your own code, please show it.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the behavior the server sees? Does it accept a socket, then block reading that socket forever, with the client also blocking forever in its `recv`? Or something different?

Comment: Finally, can you test this with a server that you know works? For example, in a terminal window, just use `nc -kl 7000` (that's for BSD netcat; different versions have slightly different parameters), then run your client. You should see `test data to transmit`, then you can type whatever you want and hit return and the client should get whatever you typed.

Comment: @abarnert I added in the server (javascript) code I'm using. When I run it the server prints out the console.log listening on the `data` event, not the body on the `close` event. When I rerun, the server shows it successfully got the data transmitted.

Comment: I used `nc -kl 7000` instead of the replacement javascript/net socket. the data from the python client goes through, printing "test data to transmit"  (Thanks for the tip about `nc` by the way. I'm reading the man pages about it now.)

Comment: If your client works with netcat as a server, but not with your custom Node server, then it sounds like the bug is in your server code. (Are you sure it's even accepting the client connection?) I'll take a look at it. But I'm still confused about what you're observing. Since the output should only be 5 lines long, can you just paste the entire "working" and "not working" output?

Comment: Sorry. I don't think I was clear. My server code (javascript) does successfully get the data from the python client. However, it behaves differently if I do run vs rerun. It doesn't make sense to me and I'm not sure if I'm asking the question in right way.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "behaves differently". Again, if you can't explain it, just show the exact sequence of things you do with the output from each step copied and pasted here. Also, please look at the answer and let me know if I'm on the wrong track.

Comment: @abarnert Great feedback on justing showing steps instead of being too verbose. :0 I just accepted the answer by the way. You figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a guess at the problem.

The client calls `sendall` to send some data, then calls `recv` to get a response.

But the server doesn't have any code anywhere to send a response. So the client will wait forever. That means it will never close the socket. Which means the `socket.on('close')` callback in your server will never get called. Since that's where you're printing the body, nothing will get printed out.

When you hit the "re-run" icon, presumably it kills the previous instance of your client before launching a new one. Killing the client will cause the socket to close, so the server will finally get to the `console.log(body)` call.

And it's definitely possible (but certainly not guaranteed) for the new client to start up and connect before the server can finish processing the old client's close, so these could show up in either order.

---

So, how can you fix this?

Well, I'm not sure whether the problem is that the client is trying to receive data when it shouldn't be expecting any, or that the server isn't sending data when it should be.

If it's the former, just remove the `data = client.recv(50)` line (and the `print` at the end) from the client.

If it's the latter, add a line somewhere in the server that sends something back to the client. You most likely want it in the `on('data')` callback, but that's not the *only* place it could conceivably make sense (for example, you could do it right at the top of the socket connection callback). And you might as well add a callback so you can see it succeeding. So:

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
    // your existing code here
    socket.write("Here's a response", function() {
        console.log('finish writing...');
    });
});
```

Comment: You nailed it. Both work. I took out the `data = client.recv(50) and print of data` and that worked. The process excited successfully with a "Process finished with exit code 0". And thus the rerun button was just a run. And hitting it transmitted the data everytime successfully. Also, I added in the `socket.write` while keeping the `recv` and that worked too.