# Python causing ECONNRESET error in Node on recv

Tags: python, node.js

Im working on a program that needs to parse JavaScript files. I'm using Node.js to host a JavaScript parser called Esprima. I'm using a TCP connection on localhost to connect to node. I have Node set up as the server and Python as the client. The Python script sends a js file to Node and Node sends the parse tree back to Python. When Python calls the sock.recv() to get the response from Node, Node recieves a ECONNRESET error.
Python is here

```
# Scancode.py

# Import libraries
import json
import sys
import glob
import errno
import socket
import os
import time
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

#Address that we will pass to the socket that we will use to talk to node
TCP_IP = 'localhost'

#The port number that we use to talk to node. It is nice and high so we don't accidentally use a common port.
TCP_PORT = 8080

#Size for the TCP buffer
BUFFER_SIZE = 20000

#acceptable number of command line arguments 
num_args = 4

#total number of possible command line options
num_optns = 1;

#error message to indicate proper usage
usage = "Error: Scancode.py [-recursive] <js-source> <xml-output>"

#get the command line arguments
args = sys.argv

#test number of arguments
if len(args) > num_args and len(args) < num_args - num_optns:
    print usage
    sys.exit(0)

#remember the name of the js path; should be the second argument
path = args[len(args) - 2]

dirs = os.listdir(path)
os.chdir(path)

myjs = []
for file in dirs:
try:
#file element in the XML
file1 = Element('file')
fname = os.path.basename(file)
    with open(file) as f:
        myjs.append(f.read())
except IOError as exc:
    if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
        raise

#Create a new TCP socket using IPv4 protocol
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#Attempt to connect to Esprima
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

#send js file over
sock.send(myjs[0])

#receive host responses
response = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

#print results in proper JSON format
print response

#close the connection
sock.send("end")
sock.close()
```

and Node is here

```
var net = require('net');
var esprima = require('esprima');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
  c.on('data', function(data) {
    if(data.toString() == "end") {
      c.end();
    } else {
      var response = JSON.stringify(esprima.parse(data, {loc: true}), null, 4);
      c.write(response)
    }   
  });

  c.on('error', function(ex) {
    console.log("handled error");
    console.log(ex);
  });
});
server.listen(8080, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

When I test with a file that is only a couple of lines everything works fine. But when I send a larger file Node gets a ECONNRESET error. Right now I have an error handler in Node but I don't know why the error is happening.

I am running on a windows machine in the command prompt by starting the Node server with the command `node host`.
 And in another command prompt I run Python with the command `Scancode.py -recursive input anything` .

With this execution the Python script expects a directory of files called input in the current working directory. My input directory contains four js files. Following are two of the files. The first one causes the error and the second one doesn't.

File1:

```
function setUser(sName, uid, name) {
    if (0 < document.getElementsByName("UID_"+sName).length) {
        popField("UID_" + sName, uid);
    }

    if (0 < document.getElementsByName("NAME_"+sName).length) {
        popField("NAME_" + sName, name);
    }

    if (0 < document.getElementsByName(sName).length) {
        popField(sName, uid);
    }

    hideElement("getUserFrame");
}

function popField(fieldName, val) {
    if (document.getElementsByName(fieldName)[0].tagName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT")
        document.getElementsByName(fieldName)[0].value = val;
    else
        document.getElementsByName(fieldName)[0].innerHTML = val;
}
function getUser(sName) {
    document.getElementById("getUserFrame").src = "/iTrust/util/getUser.jsp?s=" + sName;
    showElement("getUserFrame");
    centerElement("getUserFrame");
}
function getUserClose() {
    hideElement("getUserFrame");
}
```

File 2:

```
var answer = 42
```

If you want to test it just create a directory in the the directory that the Python script is in. And put these files in it.

On line 64: `sock.send(myjs[0])`, changing the index from 0 to 1 will send the second file instead of the first one in the directory.

I have the have Node modules esprima and net installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What factors cause data not to go through in sockets in python (or python/node.js)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849960/what-factors-cause-data-not-to-go-through-in-sockets-in-python-or-python-node-j)